# new to java/android - understanding thread inconsistent state

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I was going through [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncrgb.html) and it mentioned that an "inconsistent state" will happen if we do not synchronize these 2 lines of code. I tried to reproduce this "inconsistent state" but I was not able to do so. Can you tell me exactly what is a "inconsistent state" ?

The tutorial stated, "the value of myColorInt won't match the value of myColorName".. but I did not seem to have any problem... can you explain what exactly is the problem they are trying to avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation that is trying to be avoided is known as a *race condition*:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

The result of the sequence

```
int myColorInt = color.getRGB();      //Statement 1
String myColorName = color.getName(); //Statement 2
```

depends on the *timing* with respect to this thread of code executing in other threads.  If another thread sets the color in between these two statements, then the name stored in `myColorName` won't match the color stored in `myColorInt`.  This is what the tutorial means by *inconsistent state*.

*Synchronization* is used to make certain guarantees about how mutable data is shared and accessible across threads.  This block

```
synchronized (color) {
    int myColorInt = color.getRGB();
    String myColorName = color.getName();
}
```

uses synchronization to make sure the two statements are executed *atomically*; that is to say, to prevent another thread from changing the state of the `color` object while this thread is between the two statements (presuming that other threads are also using synchronization properly).

Concurrency and thread safety can be challenging to get correct, even for experts.  Concurrency issues result in hard to diagnose, hard to reproduce, and sporadic problems.  Since you're just starting out, I recommend avoiding concurrent programming for the time being if possible.  Otherwise, the book *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz, et. al. is an excellent start.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you don't see this problem doesn't mean it won't occur. However, it MIGHT occur and probably WILL occur at some point. This essentially means there is no guarantee about the outcome of these threads running, and without a guarantee you can't be sure what your code will do. Solution is to put it in a `synchronized` block

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean this lines from the site you linked to, that could cause an "inconsistent state" if you omit the synchronization:

```
synchronized (color) {
    int myColorInt = color.getRGB();
    String myColorName = color.getName();
}
```

Please note that both methods `getRGB()` and `getName()` are declared as `synchronized` and that the `set(…)` method also contains a `synchronized` block.

---

Now imagine this scenario: Let us forget all this `synchronized` blocks, i.e. let us see what could happen, if they would not be there. We have two threads A and B.

Thread A wants to execute the following statements:

```
color.set(0, 0, 0, "Black");
int colorIntA = color.getRGB();
String colorNameA = color.getName();
```

Thread B wants to execute the same, but with the color white:

```
color.set(255, 255, 255, "White");
int colorIntB = color.getRGB();
String colorNameB = color.getName();
```

If all goes well, `colorIntA` is 0, `colorNameA` is "Black", `colorIntB` is 16777215 and colorNameB is "White".

Now let's say the scheduler decides to interrupt execution of thread A *after* executing `getRGB()` but *before* `getName()`. In the meantime all of threadB runs. So the whole execution looks like this:

```
color.set(0, 0, 0, "Black");
int colorIntA = color.getRGB();
// here thread A is interrupted and all of thread B runs
color.set(255, 255, 255, "White");
int colorIntB = color.getRGB();
String colorNameB = color.getName();
// thread B is done, continuing with remaining statement of thread A
String colorNameA = color.getName();
```

Now all is well with `colorIntB` and `colorNameB` but the variables of thread A are inconsistent: `colorIntA` is 0 (as expected) but `colorNameA` is "White"! This is the inconsistency the tutorial talks about.

Using the `synchronized` blocks avoids this so called *race condition* by not allowing thread B to work with `color` until thread A is done with it, i.e. thread B has to wait until the `synchronized` block from thread A is finished completely.

---

You might be able to see the problem in action when you put something like the following between `getRGB()` and `getName()`, which causes a random wait between 0 and 5 seconds:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 5000));
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // not relevant in this case
}
```